# VAGRANT_LOG=DEBUG vagrant up returns the following error

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Using Vagrant version 1.2.7 with VirtualBox 4.2.10.

After pulling the following box:

https://opscode-vm-bento.s3.amazonaws.com/vagrant/opscode_ubuntu-12.04-i386_chef-11.4.4.box

and attempting to 'vagrant up', I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR vagrant: /Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.2.7/
 plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/boot.rb:17:in `call'
```

Is this a bug? Any workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to upgrade your VirtualBox to 4.2.16 and try again. The error didn't tell too much about the root cause anyway.

Comment: https://learnchef.opscode.com/quickstart/workstation-setup/  - Notice how they warn you to use an older version of vb.